# how to auto add class after 3 posts outside post loop?

Tags: loops, post

On my WordPress website in front page there is a latest post list and the structure described below. The first div contains class `music-info` contains 3 post with the same structure but the class added after that to `<div class="music-info two">` how to make this possible in wordpress post outside the `post loop`

```
<div class="music-info">
                <div class="col-md-4 music-grids">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="images/m1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h4>MUSIC ALBUM</h4>
                            <p>In sit amet sapien eros Integer in tincidunt labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>   
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>       
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 music-grids">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="images/m2.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h4>MUSIC ALBUM</h4>
                            <p>In sit amet sapien eros Integer in tincidunt labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>   
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>       
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 music-grids">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="images/m3.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h4>MUSIC ALBUM</h4>
                            <p>In sit amet sapien eros Integer  in tincidunt labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>                          
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>       
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

                <div class="music-info two">
                <div class="col-md-4 music-grids">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="images/m4.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h4>MUSIC ALBUM</h4>
                            <p>In sit amet sapien eros Integer in tincidunt labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>   
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>       
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 music-grids">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="images/m6.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h4>MUSIC ALBUM</h4>
                            <p>In sit amet sapien eros Integer in tincidunt labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>   
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>       
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 music-grids">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="images/m5.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h4>MUSIC ALBUM</h4>
                            <p>In sit amet sapien eros Integer  in tincidunt labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>                          
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>       
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

**PHP code**

```
 <?php 
                $args = array(
                'post_type'=>'product',
                'posts_per_page'=>'3'
                );
                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                /*echo"<pre>";
                print_r($query);
                die();*/

                ?>
                <div class='music-info'>
                <?php
                if($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 music-grids">
                <figure class="effect-bubba">
                    <?php 
                    if(has_post_thumbnail())
                    {
                         the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                    ?>
                        <figcaption>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>   
                    </div>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do, add a class to the third music-grids positionned inside the music-info two class ?

Comment: The first div has `<div class="music-info">` class and after 3 `<div class="col-md-4 music-grids">` the  div has `<div class="music-info two">` `two` class and its out side the post loop.

Comment: I know you're trying to explain it, but I fear we're struggling to understand what you're looking for.  Would you mind doing a couple things: 1) clean up the formatting of the code in the description, it looks like it's a little bit incorrectly formatted, and 2) post the wordpress loop code you're referring to, that might help us understand more about the context